# How to monitor single process CPU usage under AIX?

Tags: cpu, monitoring, aix

I need to analyze the CPU usage of a *single process* under AIX. Currently, I'm using `nmon` but it gets the overall CPU and IO usage. Also, I know about `topas`, but it will get the overall usage of the "hot" processes instead of a specific process.

Do such a tool exists, or should I just write my own script using `ps | grep`?

Answer (score 1):

nmon will show you the CPU usage of individual processes via the 't' display (which, amongst other things, shows top CPU usage by process).  I'm guessing if you're interested in knowing how much CPU it's using, it'll be using a fair amount?